# Why is Meteor disallowing the entry of a Password in a deploy attempt?

Tags: meteor, deployment, web-deployment, meteor-accounts, windows-console

I want to deploy my Meteor app (I've done it before without a hitch, with a different app). Now, though, it prompts me for a username (I don't recall whether it required that in the past).

Anyway, assuming that "username" is my MDG account credentials, I entered my email address for this. The cursor (in the Windows command prompt) then moves to the next line, prompting me for Password. But the cursor simply blinks there, and does not accept any input from the keyboard. Even after clicking in the blinking spot in the command prompt and trying again, nothing is accepted:

[image]

So, I eventually mash the "Enter" key and am advised, "Error deploying application: login failed"

Of course it failed - it wouldn't let me enter a password!

I did a "meteor list" in the folder, and I do see "autopublish" and "insecure" there.

So what do I need to do (if there's anything I *can* do) to deploy my app?

Comment: You are aware that password line isn't moving when you are typing? Simpy type your password and hit enter, there won't be any `*`

Comment: That would be odd - isn't the norm to show *s? Even "blindly" typing my password fails...

Comment: It seems the problem was the site name I was using ("meatier") was already taken - that's why it was prompting me. Once I used a unique name, it no longer prompted me. The owners or "meatier" were probably wondering, "Who is this cat who's trying to log in?"

Comment: I think it's a good idea password  isn't prompted - this way possible hacker knows one thing less about your password - length. Although it might be confusing to people that are not developing on Linux/Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the site name I was trying to deploy to ("meatier") has already been taken - that's why it was prompting me for username and password.

Once I used a unique name, it no longer prompted me for credentials.

The owners of "meatier" were probably wondering, "Who is this cat who's trying to log in?"

I suggest that MDG (no, not Miller Draft Genuine, but Meteor Development Group) add an explanatory note/reminder when deploying to an already-deployed site that such is the case. Otherwise, they could end up dazed and confused, like I was.